# Тип Треугольника

Tags: python

Определите тип треугольника (остроугольный, тупоугольный, прямоугольный) с данными сторонами.
Даны три натуральных числа – стороны треугольника.
Необходимо вывести одно из слов: right для прямоугольного треугольника, acute для остроугольного треугольника, obtuse для тупоугольного треугольника или impossible, если входные числа не образуют треугольника.

Почему то пишет неполное решение.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())

if (a + b > c) and (c + b > a) and (a + c > b):
    if (a*a + b*b == c*c) or (a*a + c*c == b*b) or (c*c + b*b == a*a):
        print("right")
    elif (a*a + b*b > c*c) or (a*a + c*c > b*b) or (c*c + b*b > a*a):
        print("acute")
    elif (a*a + b*b < c*c) or (a*a + c*c < b*b) or (c*c + b*b < a*a):
        print("obtuse")
else:
    print("impossible")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поменяй местами проверки на тупоугольный и остроугольный. В каждом тупоугольном треугольнике есть два острых угла, поэтому до проверки на тупоугольность твой код никогда не доходит - останавливается или на прямоугольном или на остроугольном.

Да и последний elif можно заменить на else.

```
if (a*a + b*b == c*c) or (a*a + c*c == b*b) or (c*c + b*b == a*a):
    print("right")
elif (a*a + b*b < c*c) or (a*a + c*c < b*b) or (c*c + b*b < a*a):
    print("obtuse")
else:
    print("acute")
```

Comment: я туплю к ночи, или правда достаточно самую длинную сравнивать с суммой других?

Comment: Точно, спасибо! Помогло

Comment: @splash58 да фиг его знает, это так давно было 

Comment: Самая длинная сторона всегда будет короче суммы двух других, это не работает)

Comment: @Пельмень Сплэш прав. Причем здесь сумма, если речь о теореме Пифагора?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())

if ((a*a) + (b*b)) == c*c or ((a*a) + (c*c)) == a*a or ((a*a) + (c*c)) == b*b or ((c*c) + (b*b)) == a*a:
    print('rectangular')
if a + b > c or a + c > b or a + c > b or c + b > a:
    print('acute')
if a + b < c or a + c < b or a + c < b or c + b < a:
    print('obtuse')
else:
    print('impossible')
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю использовать библиотеку sympy

```
from sympy.geometry import Triangle, Point
t1 = Triangle(Point(0, 0), Point(4, 0), Point(4, 3))
t1.is_right()
#True
t1.angles
# {Point2D(4, 3): acos(3/5), Point2D(0, 0): acos(4/5), Point2D(4, 0): pi/2}
t1.angles[Point(0,0)]
#acos(4/5)
```